# Cannot run Grails 4 multi project build with Vue profile in parallel

Tags: vue.js, gradle, grails

My multi project build has a Grails 4 server and Vue client. I have top level settings.gradle. 
The catch is that my server project also has an inline plugin dependency.
Running each individually works fine;

`./gradlew client:bootRun`

or

`./gradlew server:bootRun`

but when I try and run in parallel,

`./gradlew bootRun --parallel`

instead of the server application running, the inline plugin that it depends on is run instead for some reason?

Is there a way to configure / force the desired behaviour? I figure it has something to do with my top level settings.gradle. Details as follows;

**Directory structure**

```
|MyProject
|-- settings.gradle
|-- build.gradle
|-- client
|   |-- vue application 
|-- server 
|   |-- grails 4 application

|MyPlugin
|-- Grails plugin
```

**My settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name='MyProject'
include ':client', ':server', ':MyPlugin'
project(':MyPlugin').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../MyPlugin')
```

The plugin is included as a dependency in server's build.gradle as follows;

`compile project(':MyPlugin')`

a configuration that worked fine for me before as is necessary for our build setup.

Answer (score 0):

> instead of the server application running, the inline plugin that it
>   depends on is run instead for some reason?

When you run `./gradlew bootRun --parallel`, every subproject that has a `bootRun` task in it will get run.  That is desired Gradle behavior.

You said "instead of the server application running" which suggests something is wrong in the project, or there is a bug in Gradle.  I would expect the server to run in addition to, not instead of, all the other projects that have a `bootRun` task in them.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I can only assume that running `./gradlew server:bootRun` will not have the same effect of running the plugin's `bootRun` task and so it works as expected.